# Insert with While Loop in MySQL database table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert  a bunch of records in my MySQL database table.

I am not expert to create a stored procedure.

Here is my code:

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE var INT; 
 SET var = 0; 
 WHILE var < 100000 DO 
  INSERT INTO stored_copy (total, active, stored) VALUES (var, 1, 1);
  SET var = var + 1; 
 END WHILE; 

END;
```

Here is the error:

[image]

Can anyone check what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

stored is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html) you have to use backticks

see also [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

```
BEGIN

 DECLARE var INT; 
 SET var = 0; 
 WHILE var < 100000 DO 
  INSERT INTO stored_copy (total, active, `stored`) VALUES (var, 1, 1);
  SET var = var + 1; 
 END WHILE; 

END;
```

Answer (score 1):

[Update the name](https://www.1keydata.com/sql/alter-table-rename-column.html) of "stored" column in stored_copy table.
stored is a reserved word.